# Gradle - cannot find symbol method from support library

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I'm using following dependencies in my modules gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Code suggestions work well, but when I want to compile, I get following error:

> Error:(285, 27) error: cannot find symbol method collapseActionView(MenuItem)
>
> Error:(397, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getChildFragmentManager()

What am I missing? Those methods are part of the above mentioned libraries and should be found...

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Some other gradle imported library had an old support library in it (for me it was greendao)...